# C++ Destructor call Class Pointer called in Another class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, destructor

I am working on a school project where I have to parse information from a string array and then place them into an object (class1) of one class using an array of pointers called in another class (class2). I am able to get the information into the class1 object but when I try to remove a single class1 object using the pointer in class 2 either nothing happens, I can empty an array stored in class1 object, or I receive scope errors (cannot delete expression of type class1), depending on how I manipulate my code. Here is a small sample:

```
 class Class1 {
 public:
  //Declare constructors
  Class1 (int num, string word, int array[]);
  Class1 ();

  //Destructor
  ~Class1();
  };

   Class1::~Class1(){}
    //followed by definitions assigning variables using this->num = num; etc...

    //Declare Class2
   class Class2 {
   public:
   int index = 0;
   int numStudent;
   //Constructors
   Class2(numStudent);
   Class2();

   ~Class2();
 
   Class1* arrayPtr[5];
   };
   
     //Class2 Definitions
     Class2::Class2 (int numStudent) {
      this->numStudent = numStudent;
      for (int i = 0; i < numStudent; ++i) {
       arrayPtr[i] = new Class1;
     }
     }

     Class1::Class1(){}
     //
     Class2::~Class2() {
        delete[] arrayPtr;
     }
```

This way I receive an error on Class2 destructor to "Cannot delete expression of type 'Class1 *[3]'. I tried using delete arrrayPtr[I] in a for loop and received no error, outputted message saying Object Removed but recalling print still printed the Object that was supposed to be removed. Any explanation or tips would be helpful.

Comment: The current C++ guideline is not to use `int* array;`, but to use `std::vector<int>` or if you must allocate memory manually use `std::unique_ptr, std::make_unique` (and point this out to your teacher). However if you need to stick to the assignment and use raw pointers then delete the array using `new arr[num]; delete[] arr;`.

Comment: You don't `new[]` the array. Why do you want `delete[]` it?

Comment: It would help, in both your understanding of the problem and explaining the potential solution(s), if you removed all of the unnecessary clutter and illegitimate fantasy code in that code list, stripping it down to a proper [mcve].  And supporting Pepjin's comment, using a vector has the added bonus of no longer requiring managing a `numStudent` member, since that information would already be provided by way of the vector's `size()` result.

Answer (score 1):

##### Mistake 1

The error means that you're trying to use `delete[]` on `arrayPtr` which is an *array of size 3 with elements of type `Class*`*. In other words, the operand for the `delete[]` in your example is an array and not a pointer. That is, the operand to `delete` or `delete []` should be a pointer.

##### Mistake 2

Secondly, nowhere in your program you've used `new[]` form so using `delete[]` is incorrect. That is, since you've used `new` form, you should be using the `delete` form instead of `delete[]`.

The correct way to do this would be to loop through the array using a say `for` loop and then using `delete` form on each element.

---

Note also that better would be to either use smart pointers or better yet use `std::vector` so that you don't have to do explicit memory management using `new` and `delete`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I do agree using a vector would be better but we specifically have to use arrays for the assignment. I did attempt to use a for loop and then receive the following error: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT , as well as: malloc: *** error for object 0x1011ca8c0: pointer being freed was not allocated C867_Task1(58147,0x10009c580) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug.